# Do or does with your

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. Your mother doesn’t have a car.
> 2. Your mother do not have a car.

And why do we use **"have"** with both these sentences? Why don't we use **"has"**?

Comment: Please show us some research for this.  What is the third person negative of any verb in English? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence is correct. This is the general structure:

"I, You, We, They" + **have / do**

"He, She, It, a proper noun like John etc" + **has / does**

"Your mother" refers to "she", so you should use "doesn't".

> Your mother doesn’t have a car.

About your second question, "doesn't" is an auxiliary verb and we use the base form of the verb after do / does / did (have is the base form of *"to have"*)